# How to get INCLUDE_END_DATE result if not using php 8.2 and above?

Tags: php

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'INCLUDE_END_DATE'**

Getting this above error if php version is less than 8.2 with following code.

```
    $begin = new \DateTime('2023-04-03');
    $end = new \DateTime('2023-04-04');
    
    $interval = \DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
    $period = new \DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end, \DatePeriod::INCLUDE_END_DATE);
    
    foreach ($period as $dt) {
        echo $dt->format("Y-m-d") ."<br />";
    }
```

The output of the above code should be

```
    2023-04-03
    2023-04-04
```

Comment: `INCLUDE_END_DATE` would be the difference between using `00:00:00` and `23:59:59`, right?

Comment: Not sure about the difference, but passing it gives the end date in the output. if you do not pass it.. it will output only one day

Comment: Test it out I think include the time will give the results your require, https://3v4l.org/i7kQf.

Answer (score 1):

You can add 1 day to the end time like this:

```
$begin = new \DateTime('2023-04-03');
$end = new \DateTime('2023-04-04 +1 day'); // Change is here

$interval = \DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new \DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format("Y-m-d") ."<br />";
}
```

This results in the expected output for PHP 8.1, 8.0 and 7.4.

You can check it here: https://onlinephp.io/c/a3f00

Comment: @SyedWaqasBukhary I forgot to remove the INCLUDE_END_TIME from my answer. This will work the same on PHP 8.2 as well. This tests for PHP 7.4, 8.0, 8.1, 8.2 https://onlinephp.io/c/42365

Comment: let me try this with different inputs, and end of year days and end of Febs

Comment: Seems to be working, will check further later